# Quote tags in Hugo frontmatter (regex help!)

Tags: regex, awk, sed, hugo, quoting

In the process of converting a blog from WordPress to Hugo, I find that I need to do a global search and replace for tags to convert them to a list of strings.

Currently I have something like this:

```yaml
tags: owl, owl2, rdfs, rdf, snippets, vscode, visual studio code
```

But I need something like this:

```yaml
tags: ["owl", "owl2", "rdfs", "rdf", "snippets", "vscode", "visual studio code"]
```

I have a variety of editors such as VSCode, VS22, Neovim, Rider etc. at my disposal as well as sed, gawk etc, so any solution will do.

Comment: PS  I need to do this on over 400 posts, so I'm after a solution that can do everything at once....

Comment: Try Notepad++ editor.  It has a regex search and replace, and you can use them across a list of files.

Comment: thanks.  The same is true of VSCode.  My problem is with expanding out a repeating group given a capture.  Using the capture only gives me the last match...

Comment: Are you sure none of the strings in WordPress could contain commas?

Answer (score 0):

To find all these with such a pattern: `^(tags: )|(, )|$`.

Then the expected result for a given string can be achieved in 3 steps using VSCode:

1. Search for a string `tags:`  (**note** there is a space) using `command+F`/`cntrl+F` and to a `Replace` field add a string `tags: ["`.
2. Search for `,`  (**note** there is a space) and replace it with `", "`.
3. Depending on what's at the end of the line search for `$` or `\n` (in a search dialog select **Use Regular Expression** option) and replace it with `"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
tags: owl, owl2, rdfs, rdf, snippets, vscode, visual studio code
```

then

```
sed -e 's/ /["/' -e 's/$/"]/' -e 's/, /", "/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
tags:["owl", "owl2", "rdfs", "rdf", "snippets", "vscode", "visual studio code"]
```

Explanation: I give three instructions

- replace space using `["` once (i.e. it will affect only first space)
- replace end of line using `"]` (i.e. append `"]`)
- replace `,`  using `", "` globally (i.e. it wil affect all `,` )

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*